# ¿Que significan los signos "<>" antes de una funcion?

Tags: c#

Estoy entendiendo un código pero me encuentro con esta sintaxis

```
abreforma<Usuario.PrincipalUsuario>();
```

No entiendo que significa lo que esta en medio de los signos "<>"

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, En cuanto a tu pregunta revisa antes en el sitio posiblemente ya esta respondida tu pregunta, en este caso revisa la respuesta de @A.Cedano, saludos!

Comment: Revisa: https://www.dotnetperls.com/generic

Comment: El método es genérico, es decir, puede aceptar datos de distintos tipos. Con los <> le indicas el tipo específico que va a utilizar el método. un ejemplo de genéricos lo tienes en las listas, una lista de números enteros es List<int> y una lista de strings es List<string>, ambas son listas de elementos, pero la primera guarda enteros y la otra strings.

Comment: @Jorgesys la pregunta del OP se refiere a C#, mientras que la marcada como duplicada es java. No se si es muy correcto enlazar preguntas de dos lenguajes diferentes.